# How do I prove that my Double.toString algorithm is correct for all values?

Tags: java, double, tostring, floating

I'm working on optimizations to Java's notoriously slow Double.toString algorithm. I've already successfully rewritten Float.toString (and gotten an over 400% improvement in speed). Testing Float.toString's algorithm was easy because I can iterate throw all possible values (from Integer.MIN_VALUE to Integer.MAX_VALUE) in about the time it takes to boil an egg.

However, testing Double.toString for accuracy the same way would require that I iterate from Long.MIN_VALUE to Long.MAX_VALUE. I could start this test on all threads and run it for the rest of my life and I bet it wouldn't finish.

To be clear, when I'm testing this algorithm, I'm simply taking my resultant String and calling String.equals on it against the result from java.lang.Double.toString(double d). If they match, I move onto the next value.

My improvement to the algorithm primarily involves eliminating unnecessary precision. When Double.toString is calculated, it uses a special sort of BigInteger class to do this. However, I've found that by trimming insignificant bits, I can still get the same result with a significant performance improvement.

I think that I can trim all values to no more than 128 bits (with the trimmed bits replaced with an offset) without failing my test, but how can I prove this without iterating over every value?

I guess what I'm asking is: How did the creators of the original algorithm know with absolute certainty that their algorithm was correct without testing every possible input?

Comment: You are right when you say `and I bet it wouldn't finish`, since floats represent real numbers and between 0 and 1 there is actually an **infinite** amount of those. To be more precise between any two real numbers there is an **infinite** amount of other real numbers.

Comment: Another result of this is that a float can never correctly represent all real numbers, just the ones that fit into it. There are only **non-significant** bits, if the current value stored in the float has only so few digits after 0 that they fit in there and can be represented binary wise. 0.1 for example cannot be presented binary wise since it is 1/10.

Comment: For practical purposes, in Java there are 2^64 possible inputs to Double.toString. Some of these resolve to identical values (NaN). Half are negative. There's negative and possitive infinity and negative and positive zero. A few can be resolved using a slightly modified Long.toString algorithm.
Most, however, are calculated by finding values b and s such that (b/s)*10^decExp = double value. The decimal exponent is estimated and adjusted as needed.

Comment: @JohnSmith Your comments contradict each other. You can easily (though it'd be time-consuming) iterate over all possible floats, because _they don't represent every real number_, as you say in your first comment; your second is accurate in that the finite precision means that some "nearby" numbers are clumped together, and numbers whose binary representation has an infinite number of digits are truncated. That finite precision means that yes, it is possible to iterate over every float, if only by starting at the one represented by 32 0s, then incrementing it like a binary integer until 32 1s.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not...entirely sure they did.

You can look at [the OpenJDK 8](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/test/java/lang/Double) and [OpenJDK 9](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/jdk/file/f3013adf1e3d/test/java/lang/Double) tests written for `Double#toString`, and not get much...satisfaction from it:

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
 * DO NOT ALTER OR REMOVE COPYRIGHT NOTICES OR THIS FILE HEADER.
 *
 * This code is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
 * under the terms of the GNU General Public License version 2 only, as
 * published by the Free Software Foundation.
 *
 * This code is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but WITHOUT
 * ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or
 * FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU General Public License
 * version 2 for more details (a copy is included in the LICENSE file that
 * accompanied this code).
 *
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License version
 * 2 along with this work; if not, write to the Free Software Foundation,
 * Inc., 51 Franklin St, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA 02110-1301 USA.
 *
 * Please contact Oracle, 500 Oracle Parkway, Redwood Shores, CA 94065 USA
 * or visit www.oracle.com if you need additional information or have any
 * questions.
 */

/*
 * @test
 * @bug 4428022
 * @summary Tests for Double.toString
 * @author Andrew Haley <aph@redhat.com>
 */

public class ToString {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
      if (!Double.toString(0.001).equals("0.001"))
          throw new RuntimeException("Double.toString(0.001) is not \"0.001\"");
      if (!Double.toString(0.002).equals("0.002"))
          throw new RuntimeException("Double.toString(0.001) is not \"0.002\"");
    }
}
```

Effectively, all they're doing is testing *two* cases; if the `toString` method correctly identifies `"0.001"` and `"0.002"` as returning satisfactorily.

This *may* have to do with the fact that floating-point numbers are notoriously bad at handling those kinds of fractions, which would be a decent acid test for anything trying to convert a double to a string in that fashion; it was very much the case that they simply created one test to cover the basics.

Take from that what you will; I'd encourage you to think a bit harder on what else you want to test.  From this, it looks like only the edge cases are caught; you may want to expand on that with your own optimizations.

Although...adding these tests (in a better way, mind you) to your own suite wouldn't be the worst idea, either.  They haven't changed since '09.

Comment: Wow....that's all they tested?
I can assure you there are quite a few more test cases that would be valid than that. I know, for example, that there are (at the very least) 4 or 5 major sub-cases in the algorithm that handle the computations completely differently. How can all of those cases be tested? It's not particularly confidence-boosting to know how little it was tested.

Comment: Well no, I wouldn't imagine that your confidence would be particularly high after seeing that this is literally *it* to testing `Double#toString`.  To answer your follow-up:  test those components directly.  Think of each case that each component is designed to handle, and test the cases around those.